# OpenGl performance/hinderance gain?

Tags: android, performance, opengl-es

In OpenGL (ES for Android if it matters), is using `GL10.glTranslatef(x, y, z);` then drawing an object (in my case a hexagon tile) more efficient / practical than passing the new coordinates to the object and refactoring the buffers (if need be)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That depends on the rest of your code. It's likely to be a negligible difference if you're talking about the difference for a single quad, for example. The golden rule is to avoid state changes and to optimise geometry around that aim. If you have, say, 10000 tiles that you can draw in a single call to `glDrawElements` or `glDrawArrays` if you translate in your code and upload vertex locations en masse then it's as certain as it can be that you'll see an improvement. If you're doing one call to `glDrawElements` or `glDrawArrays` per tile then you're unlikely to notice any difference either way.

So: it's a worthwhile change if it allows you to batch more geometry together, otherwise it's probably not going to make much odds. From my anecdotal experience, on a first generation iOS device, which had a PowerVR MBX, with a sprite-style engine, I went from the device struggling a little with a few hundred sprites to it being able to handle thousands. Batching my geometry meant that GPU/CPU synchronisation was no longer the bottleneck.